# Assembly language instructions

Tags: assembly

Need help in developing Assembly language instructions for the following piece of code.

```
a = 0;
i = 0;
while (i < 10) do
a = a + i;
i = i + 1;
endwhile
```

I am very confused on how to do this. The book that I have is very confusing and does not show any examples of any kind to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What *does* your book describe, then? You make it sound as if you're looking at the wrong book.

Comment: There are more than one assembly languages. Please specify which CPU and assembler you're targeting, and also show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

In x86 assembly your code can be translated into this(using just 2 regular purpose 16bit registers):

```
mov ax, 0     # a = 0
mov cx, 0

.label:       # a label so you can jump later
add ax, cx    # add CX to AX(a = a + i)
inc cx        # increase CX(i = i + 1)
cmp cx, 10    # compare CX with 10
jl .label     # if CX < 10 then jump to label
```

CX is used for loops. The above code is 100 copy of your code. If you do not mind i going down from 10 to 1, code looks like this:

```
mov ax, 0     # a = 0
mov cx, 10

.label:       # a label so you can jump later
add ax, cx    # add CX to AX(a = a + i)
loop label    # CX = CX - 1. If CX > 0 jump to label
```

Comment: Just a comment: This code might have a problem if assembled in 32 Bit mode, as the loop instruction will use ECX, where the upper word is undefined. So either it must be assembled as a 16 Bit program, or it should be `mov ecx, 10`.

Comment: @Devolus it might be. it might as well be an error in loop label as in some assemblers it should be loop .label and in some other assemblers .label is a local label and just "label" is possible. In either way I assume OP doesn't even understand how to do the task

Comment: A syntatical error would be thrown by the assembler. This one not. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't (at time of writing) specified which Assembler platform you're talking about, here's some 6502 which replicates your functionality:

```
        LDA #$00   ; initialise tally (a = 0)
        LDX #$09   ; initialise counter (i = 9)
.LOOP   STX .COUNT ; save counter for addition
        CLC        ; clear carry flag before addition
        ADC .COUNT ; add counter to tally (a = a + i)
        DEX        ; decrement counter
        BPL .LOOP  ; keep adding until counter drops below zero
        RTS        ; finished, return (.A contains result)
.COUNT  DS #$00    ; counter work area
```

Edited after my inability to properly distinguish between '1' and 'i' in the question was kindly pointed-out. ;)

Comment: @Michael Oops well-spotted. Time for new specs I think. Answer (heavily) modified accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gcc` to generate assembly from C code. For example, create `main.c` with:

```
main() {
    int a = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        a = a + i;
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Then run

```
gcc -c -S main.c
```

That'll give you `main.s` with the assembly representation.

Answer (score 0):

Similar code would be generated for IA-32 using GNU tool chain, AT&T syntax...

```
            movl $0, -4(%ebp)                # local variable a
            movl $0, -8(%ebp)                # local variable i

            jmp condition
while:
            # a = a + i
            movl -8(%ebp), %eax              # move i to %eax
            addl %eax, -4(%ebp)              # add %eax to a

            # i = i + 1
            addl $1, -8(%ebp)                # add 1 to i

condition:
            movl -8(%ebp), %eax              # move i to %eax
            cmpl $10, %eax                   # compare %eax with 10
            jl while                         # jump if i < 10
```